# Eagle Cad Resize PCB

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, cad, dimensions

I am having trouble resizing the PCB after components have been placed. I know this is not the usual method, but I have been given a .brd file and .sch and the board dimensions were decided already. Now I would like to move a few things about and create space to shuffle things about and add to the schematic, but could someone please help me increase the PCB size please?

I wondered if I did resize it relative to the origin, would the components not be centred any more and how would I get them back in line too?

I would be very grateful for any help from here please!

Answer (score 1):

Just move the outline that is located in the "20 Dimension" -layer? If the shape is complicated or you want to move components with the outline use the *group*-tool, select the area (including miters etc) select *move*-tool right click somewhere in the selection and select *Move: Group*

Comment: Hi Ralph thank you for your helpful reply. I did move and extend the dimension 20 on your advice and I know have much more useable board space with all thanks to you :) I think though I dimensioned with negative half inch to the left of origin and plus half inch the other side. The idea was to keep all components central but I am wondering how poor practice it is to have negative coordinates at this point.

Comment: I tend to avoid negative coordinates. You will only notice the possible problems when you send the manufacturing files to the manufacturer or try to check the files with some other SW. Or maybe in 2020 all SW can handle leading and trailing zeros, negative coordinates, non-fixed decimal point placement etc, but that wasn't the case in 2010's ;)

Comment: Vote up and mark as an answer if you are satisfied, thanks.

Comment: ah I will check! or get it sorted at the manufacturer. either way I am grateful for your help.